# Unable to change location of project in Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

[image]

Initially, name of my project was abc. I uploaded to git. Later I want to rename it as GreenKartAutomation.
I detached it from git, tried to rename but it is still showing as abc. On my harddrive, it is still saved as abc and I am unable to rename it.
I closed project, tried to rename, tried to rename from harddrive but no luck!

Comment: What is the state of things *after* you've done all of this?

Comment: In Eclipse delete the project without deleting its contents, then on the file system  rename or move it and in Eclipse open it again via _File > Open Projects form File System..._